# save Image in application in silverlight

Tags: c#, image, xaml, silverlight-4.0, webcam

I'm new to silver light 4. I need to capture Image from webcam and save into local application folder named 'temp'. When i click save button, the snapshot should save in that folder. I have searched in Google and got samples to save in local machine, but not in the application. please guide me friends.
Thanks..

Comment: can you paste some code, you have tried till now

Comment: Im trying this example [Follow the link](http://wildermuth.com/2009/11/23/Taking_a_WebCam_Photo_with_Silverlight). in this example, image is saved using SaveFileDialog. but I need to save in Application path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly access the file system from Silverlight (at least in normal browser mode). This is a security precaution to stop it being misused.

The exception to that is Isolated Storage, which is a safe area set aside for each Silverlight application to read/write from/to.

This link has some examples you can work though: [http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-(silverlight-quickstart)](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-%28silverlight-quickstart%29)